# How can I trigger GitHub Actions when pushing to an open PR?

Tags: github, github-actions

I plan to set up a GitHub Actions job when a PR is open on targeting `main` branch. Also I'd like to trigger the job when pushing a commit on the open PR.

I have below YAML on workflow file:

```yaml
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
    branches:
      - main
```

It runs when a PR on `main` is open. But I can't find a right type for pushing a commit on the open PR. What is the type I should use?

Comment: You don't need the `"types"` filter. By default `pull_request` runs when `opened` and `updated`. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/.github/workflows/pull-request.yml) an example

Comment: Note you can see all of the available events and types in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was linked in response to your question - a full list of events can be found in the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request) - this link is a direct one to the event I think you require - namely `pull_request`

I think your workflow could make use of this to achieve the desired outcome, e.g;

```
on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
      - "**/*.md"
```

This is an example from one of my own [sample repositories](https://github.com/MTJB/blog_code_examples/blob/main/.github/workflows/pull_request.yml) which I believe matches your desired outcome (new pull requests, and new changes to an existing pull request all trigger this workflow).